# How to control seek range in Exoplayer?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer-media-item

I implemented a video player using Exoplayer and it works fine.

What I need is to restrict the user to only seek to a certain position in the video and prevent him from seeking after this position.

I'm using ExoPlayer 2.19.1